# Adjusting brightness/contrast for XYZ Tile Data

Tags: qgis-3, color, xyz-tiles

Is there a way to adjust brightness and contrast for XYZ tile data in QGIS 3.4?

Specifically, I'd like to adjust the settings for the Google Imagery Hybrid XYZ tile. I'm running QGIS on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the layer to your project, you can right click it, go to Properties->Symbology. Here you can adjust brightness as well as contrast:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks.